# 'Engineer mode test tool' app - What do the codes do?

Tags: dialer-codes

I was curious and installed the [Engineer mode test tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ponphy.engineermode) app. It listed 'codes' and for most of them it wasn't written what they do. I couldn't resist stupidity and entered a few of them.

After entering one of the codes (listed under Google Service Framework in the app) my phone rebooted and the Android icon was shown and it said "erasing". I had a mini heart attack because I thought I had reset my phone. A white screen showed up saying something like "Enter password to unlock device". It said I have 30 attempts so I tried entering every password that I could remember but nothing worked. The counter said that I used just one guess no matter how many passwords I entered.

In the end I had to factory reset my phone because I needed it, but my data was on the SD card; as it was adopted I lost all my data.

What have I done by entering that code?

What was that screen that I saw?

Comment: What was the code? Where did you enter it?

Comment: @Dan Hulme I can't remember the code. I enter it in dialer

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a case for Sherlock Holmes.

You can try reinstalling the app, and checking / trying a few things that will help you remember what you did and what you got (the object of your question), in what you would consider a *harmless way*.

The follwoing lists of codes may also help you remembering; there are many other lists around. Keep in mind that some of the codes are exclusive to specific manufacturers and may not work on all brands/models/carriers.
Showing details on your case in the OP might help.
Comparing with the codes listed under Google Service Framework in the app would help narrowing down the hunting.

1. [110 Android Secret Codes, Hidden Menu, and Dialler Codes](http://joyofandroid.com/android-secret-codes-hidden-menu-dialler-codes/).
2. [Secret Codes : Use at your own risk](http://joestechreview.ning.com/page/secret-codes).
3. [Hidden Android Secret Codes & Their Usage](http://anonhq.com/hidden-android-codes-usage/).
4. [Android Hidden Codes](https://www.xda-developers.com/codes-hidden-android/).

Once you know the code you entered, it is likely trivial to answer your questions:

> What have I done by entering that code?
>   
>   What was that screen that I saw?

Comment: I'm not much interested in discovering what code it was, than what it done, I described what screen look like, I'm curios and sure I'm not the only one who been there.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје - Finding out the code is clearly not the goal. But it will put you on the verge of it. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah I could reinstall app but in that app when tap on some code it has same effect like you entered it in a dialer, and I don't have nerves for factory sesrt again. I took a look on theese codes but none of them is responsible for screen I've gotten.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје - Using the little information you have... How many codes are listed under Google Service Framework, in the app? Are the numbers for those codes also listed, or only a description of their action?

Comment: There is 9 codes under google services, first one is lg hidden menu (or at least it says that) for other codes it only says google services framework or google play services. I tried googling some of them but didn't fin anything usefull.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје - A few carifications are likely needed: 1) I guess "There is 9 codes under google services" means "There is 9 codes under Google Service Framework", is that so?. 2) Still you did not mention if the dialer codes are listed. 3) It would be useful if you post images of whatever you see under Google Service Framework. Posting as much information as possible helps others help you.